# RAD Studio как альтернатива Qt и Xamarin

Tags: delphi, qt, ide, xamarin

Задался тут вопросом по поводу наболее простого и эффективного кросплатформенного фреймворка. Облазив форумы увидел такую картину, что лидерами как правило являются PhoneGap, Xamarin, Unity, Qt. (Вот апример относительно свежий пост https://habr.com/post/319348/) -  в нем например RAD Studio совсем нет.

А вот если заходишь на узкоспециализированные форумы посвященные Delphi, то там все в один голос твердят что по широте возможностей, по простоте и скорости разработки да и по кроссплатформенности Fire Monkey (которая поставляется с RAD Studio) равных нет. Что мол Qt и Xamarin и рядом не стояли. Официальный сайт RAD Studio тоже самое говорит в общем то.

ТОгда возникает логический вопрос: если RAD Studio на столько крут, то почему его нет в рейтингах фреймворкоф? Он все таки не так крут как говорят его фанаты, или он является самым недооценненным фреймворком?

Comment: Он все таки не так крут как говорят его фанаты. Пытался на нем разрабатывать, правда, под десктоп (кроссплатформенность была нужна Windows-macOS), а оказалось, что в Tokyo в 2017 году по-прежнему нету возможности подключить Awesomium (написание своих хедеров не в счет), причем, не только в Delphi, но и в C++ Builder. А-ха-ха... Так я еще потыкался с CEF, но с ним не получалось - что-то не работало, кроме того фич "общего назначения" (типа как для файлов и процессов) там может и много по сравнению с Delphi 7, но никак не с .NET 4, и в итоге бросил и сделал все на C#.

Comment: Хотя, конечно, понятно, что разработка на кроссплатформенном фрейворке - это всегда отчасти "разработка самого фреймворка", "if-винда-...-elseif-линукс-...", но тут явно есть и покруче. Опять же, сама возможность интегрировать C# или HTML/CSS/JS стоит большего, чем Delphi или C++ (тем более такой редкий диалект, как билдеровский).

Comment: Я не думаю, что вы получите полноценный ответ на свой вопрос. Всё высказываемое будет частным мнением, основанном на "я это умею готовить, а вот там попробовал - и не получилось, значит оно - кака", что, само собой, не может являться объективным критерием. FMX достаточно хорош. Подводных камней и ограничений хватает в любом фреймворке. Сообщество Delphi не настолько большое, как у остальных. Имхо, это и есть основная проблема - мало квалифицированных кадров.

Comment: Есть еще проблема с ценой - PhoneGap, Xamarin, Qt, да и Unity можно использовать бесплатно, пусть с оговорками, но можно, а у RAD Studio только триал в 30 дней и зверская цена в несколько десятков, а то и сотен тысяч рублей. Также раньше была (а может и сейчас есть) какая-то жесть с работой под iOS - сама студия критится на винтовом компе, а отладка через мак что неудобно (ну и плюс опять-таки вопрос что тебе нужно два компа вместо одного что дорого). А учитывая что кроссплатформа обычно в первую очередь экономия на разработке/поддержке, такие затраты выглядят уж очень большими

Comment: `нужно два компа вместо одного что дорого` - интересно, как это вы соберете iOS приложение без XCode, который запускается только на маке? В любом случае нужен либо Мак, либо виртуалка с макОс. Последнее - очень даже приемлимый вариант. Говорят, что на виртуалке работает даже быстрее.

Comment: А почему вы решили что я хочу собирать iOs приложение без Xcode? Можно же добиться чтобы твоя среда для кроссплатформенной разработке работала на других платформах Qt Creator и Xamarin Studio так и делают, но не RAD Studio и именно это я считаю проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

*Пишу на Delphi (VCL), C# (Winforms). Пробовал для себя Qt. Это конечно скромный список. Но его достаточно для некоторых выводов.*

`Тогда возникает логический вопрос: если RAD Studio на столько крут, то почему его нет в рейтингах фреймворкоф?`

Его нет потому что он морально устарел. Когда то давно он был очень популярен за счет простоты разработки для того времени. Но время прошло, а Delphi практически не изменился. Да вы до сих пор можете накидать компонентики на форму, запили конект к базе и оно все будет работать. Но увы сейчас для полноценного фреймворка (особенно кросплатформеного) это уже мало.

В добавок к этому сам язык (Delphi) развивается очень слабо и явно не поспевает за другими популярными языками.

И еще немаловажный факт - это конский ценник. У нас в стране конечно все знают как бесплатно купить, но вот на западе не все такие *продвинутые*. Сейчас конечно есть бесплатная редакция среды с кучей ограничений, но... Qt creator бесплатный и Visual Studio Community практически не отличается от платных редакций.

**PS:**
Хоть Delphi устарел все же совсем со счетов его списывать пока его не стоит. Простота кидания компонентиков, и легкий язык позволит вам сделать простое приложения для себя (ну с условием что язык вы знаете).

Если вы только в начале пути, то лучше изучите что то другое.

Comment: "Последние существенное изменение языка было в Delphi 2009" - вы что-то путаете или сильно отстали от жизни. Эмбаркадера очень авктивно вливала новые фичи в язык перед продажей Идере.

Comment: @Kromster Я не утверждаю что они вообще ни чего не делали, но делали они в основном сахар. Конечно какие нибудь record helpers это удобные вещи, но это сахар.

Comment: всё можно обозвать сахаром, так что не вводите людей в заблуждение. Вот тут хороший список фич по версиям - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460037

Comment: прошу вас либо убрать субъективное мнение (абзац про якобы отсутствие новых фич с 2009) из ответа, либо хорошенько аргументировать его.

Answer (score 1):

Lazarus + FPC полностью поддерживает виджеты Win32, GTK1, GTK2, Carbon, Qt. Тот же Delphi, работает и в Windows и в Linux и на MacOs и т.п.
Последние релизы вполне достойные, работоспособные, и что не маловажно, удобны в использовании. Выбрал для новых проектов и не жалею. Старые поддерживаю на Delphi XE... Если страшно то можно писать в режиме совместимости с Delphi (на случай перехода назад).